# Jui DatePicker ignores language setting

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-ui-datepicker

Code for date field is:

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'created')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-control'
    ],
    'language' => 'ru',
    'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    ]
)
?>
```

Unfortunately, final datepicker looks completely untranslated.

Of cousre, config/web.php contains `'language' => 'ru'` item.

What's wrong?

Comment: This is not how jQuery UI datepicker works see: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

Comment: The question is not in general - how to localize DatePicker. My question is - how to localize DatePicker in Yii2. I explores from console output, and found that no file datepicker-ru.js in web assets. But how to put it safe in web assets?

Answer (score 0):

Use the recommended format for the locale id for your language [ICU Locale](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale#TOC-The-Locale-Concept)

ie:

```
'language' => 'ru-RU',
```

Comment: It is not working - again `datepicker-ru.js` not found

Comment: which datepicker widget class are you using.

Comment: `yii\jui\DatePicker`

Comment: check if you can find that file in : vendor\bower/jquery-ui\ui\i18n